# Jest only run tests that end in .test.js inside "__tests__" folder

Tags: javascript, regex, jestjs

Answer: it had nothing to do with the regex but with the position of the `jest.config.js` file, changing `rootDir`in the config fixed the issue

I have a working regex in regex101.com but I can make it work in Jest

```
__tests__\/.*test.[jt]sx?$
```

result given (regex101):

```
__tests__/__config/jest.config.js -> no
__tests__/app.test.js -> yes
__tests__/app.test.ts -> yes
__tests__/app.test.tsx -> yes
__tests__/api/app.test.js -> yes
__tests__/api/app.test.not -> no
__tests__/api/api2/api3/app.test.js -> yes
toto.test.js -> no
```

which is exactly what I want, but when I update the `jest.config.js`

Jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  testRegex: ["__tests__/.*test.[jt]sx?$"],
};
```

it doesn't find anything.

**What I'm looking to do**: I want to store everything related to unit testing inside the `__tests__` folder, including the `jest.config.js` and other stuff that does not has to be run by Jest.

In *package.json* run the config inside the `__tests__` folder

```
...
"test": "jest --config ./__tests__/__config/jest.config.js"
...
```

So it gives me something like:

```
__tests__/
    __config/
        jest.config.js -> do not run
        dabatase.js -> do not run
    user/
        user.test.js -> run this
        user.mock.js -> do not run
```

So basically only the things that end in `.test.js/ts` that are inside the `__tests__` folder

Here is a small repo with the current (non functional) config: [Github Repo](https://github.com/Antoine-lb/jest-regex-config)

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps with a leading `/` like `/__tests__/.*test.[jt]sx?$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird didn't work :S

Comment: That regex works fine for me, it makes me question if the issue isn't the regex, but rather how you are calling Jest or the architecture of your project.

Could you provide more details on these items, or if you are open to sharing the repo that would be even better

Comment: @Jacob I added a link with a very simple version so it can be checked

Comment: It was a set-up problem, thanks for the help